# jQuery Dropdown flickers in Firefox, does not work in Chrome or Safari

Tags: jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu

My dropdown fade effect that I use on regular HTML/CSS sites is not working too well with this WordPress site:  http://174.120.235.57/~phvne/

I'm putting the script calls in the footer right before the closing body tag.

I'm new with using jQuery and WordPress...any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Here's the jQuery code I'm using:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    var speed=500;
    $('#nav li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $('ul', this).fadeIn(speed);
        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $('ul', this).fadeOut(speed);           
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome (17) and Firefox (5.0.1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
var speed = 500; 
$('#nav li').hover(
    function () {
      //show its submenu
     $('ul', this).stop(true).slideDown(speed);
    },
    function () {
      //hide its submenu
     $('ul', this).stop().hide(speed);      
    }
  );
});
```

That's what I use for my dropdown, and it works fine.

Comment: I tried the code and it's not working quite right.  I have it on the site now.  http://174.120.235.57/~phvne/  Some of the dropdowns will work and other dropdowns won't.  I must be calling the scripts in a wrong way or something...

Comment: How come you dropdrows don't slideDown? Like there suppose too.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be safe, you may want to avoid conflict with other JQuery on the page.
For example, you may try the following:

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
    var speed=500;
    $j('#nav li').hover(
        function () {
            //show its submenu
            $j('ul', this).fadeIn(speed);
        }, 
        function () {
            //hide its submenu
            $j('ul', this).fadeOut(speed);           
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Hmm...I put replaced my code with this and it didn't work at all.  Thanks for both of your answers...I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: I updated the code. I changed the $ to $j within the ready function to use the correct JQuery

Comment: Also you may want to try putting you JQuery script in the head tag. You can use the following action hook to access the head from within your plugin. `add_action('wp_head', 'your_function');`